# Updating min and max values with ArcPy on stretched raster symbology in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcpy, raster, symbology, arcgis-pro

I have a map I am making where all I want to do is change the source layer for a raster to a new layer.  I would then like to apply the same symbology as the original layer, but change the min and max values used to stretch the raster.

So far I have done this:

```
import arcpy

#load in aprx
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("in_aprx")

#get the maps
one = aprx.listMaps()[0]

#update the current raster with a new raster, this new raster has different min and max values which is what I ultimately want to change

one.updateConnectionProperties(original_layer, new_layer)

#save a copy 
aprx.saveACopy("new_map.aprx")
```

I can access the layers symbology like so:

```
one_layers = one.listLayers()

one_layers[0].symbology
```

but I am not sure how to change the min and max values from here.  As of now the minimum and maximum are being used from `original_layer` which are very different and results in poor stretching.

Answer (score 0):

The python Cartographic Information Model (CIM) can recalculate stats from an histogram using Arcpy on ArcGIS Pro 2.8:

```
import arcpy

#ArcGIS Pro workspace to be modified
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("ArcGISProject_URI_Path")
for m in aprx.listMaps():
    ll = m.listLayers()
    for lyr in ll:
        ln = lyr.name
        # Return the layer's CIM definition
        cim_lyr = lyr.getDefinition('V2')
        #Calculate new stats from histogram
        symb = cim_lyr.colorizer
        symb.statsHistogram(ln)
        #Update header CIM object
        lyr.setDefinition(cim_lyr)
```